# Start python script with keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, shortcut-keys

I want to start this script with a keyboard shortcut. But no luck and I have tried "everything".

https://github.com/cas--/PasteImg/blob/master/pasteimg

My best guess is:

`/usr/bin/python ~/pasteimg/pasteimg.py ~/Downloads/screenshot.png`

But it fails silently (like all my other tries).

Can anybody help?

Comment: 1. Does it fail silently when running from the terminal as well? Generally once you get it to work in terminal, then it is easy to assign a shortcut to it. 
2. What window manager or desktop environment or distro are you using? Regular Ubuntu?

Comment: As you can see, the (ancient) script is in python2, not installed on 18.04. The question is if it would work anyway, since the last commit was... 9 years ago, Trying from the terminal would have given you more info. Furthermore, ~ does not work from a shortcut, unless you use "/bin/bash -c "<command>". Oh, and please don't "I tried everything".

Comment: From terminal it works fine. Sorry not to explicitly stating that. I only tried commands that work from terminal.

Comment: I use Ubuntu standard 18.04

Comment: python2 must be installed as a dependency of something then... Simply `python /path/to/script /path/to/file.png` should work. So no `~`!

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me (ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome)

I wrote a simple script to move my mouse to a random point, just to see some action.

In keyboard settings you can see all gnome shortcuts, at the bottom there's a button to add your own shortcuts. So just add the full path to python and the script, give it a name and set the keys you want to trigger.

In my case:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/myuser/scripts/myscript
```

as:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of '~' in '~/pasteimg/pasteimg.py' and '~/Downloads/screenshot.png', use the full path ie `/usr/bin/python /home/user/pasteimg/pasteimg.py /home/user/Downloads/screenshot.png` Replace 'user' with your username

Comment: Thank you for contributing.  Please register your account and perhaps give your account a more "human" name.